# Multiple links to same view but dynamically display the data based on a value?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using .NET MVC and I want these 5 links to all link to one view, but the data on this next View is dynamically displayed depending on the link that was clicked because of an attribute that is attached to it. (for e.g. store ID).

So if the user clicks the first link on the current View, then the StoreProducts View will only display data based on that StoreID value that is associated with that store. (Passing the value of storeID based on the link clicked).

```
<a asp-action="StoreProducts">Store1</a> |
<a asp-action="StoreProducts">Store2</a> |
<a asp-action="StoreProducts">Store3</a> |
<a asp-action="StoreProducts">Store4</a> |
<a asp-action="StoreProducts">Store5</a> |
```

I thought maybe ViewBag or ViewData would work but I cannot figure out the syntax for it or if there are any better ways to do this.

How do I pass or attach this storeID value based on the link clicked?

Comment: Do you mean, "how do I pass storeIDs from the controller to the view?" Or, "how do I pass the storeID back to the controller when the link is clicked?"

Comment: Sorry the second question.. pass the storeID back to the controller when the link is clicked.  But each link would have its own hard coded value e.g. first link has a value of 1 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing along the tag helper-based solution that you started, as well as the `asp-action` tag helper, MVC can let you assign a route argument using `asp-route-{value}`.

```
<a asp-action="StoreProducts" asp-route-id="1">Store 1</a> |
<a asp-action="StoreProducts" asp-route-id="2">Store 2</a> |
<a asp-action="StoreProducts" asp-route-id="3">Store 3</a> |
<a asp-action="StoreProducts" asp-route-id="4">Store 4</a> |
<a asp-action="StoreProducts" asp-route-id="5">Store 5</a>
```

Assuming you are using a standard route in the form of `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, this should pass the id to the `id` parameter of your `StoreProducts` action.

[It's fully detailed here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're looking for is probably a Html.ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("text","action","controller",new {id = value},new{HtmlAttribute})
```

Which in yoru case would be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Store1","StoreProducts","controller",new {id = 1},null)
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know whether this is good solution or not but still i will try to explain: First all you will have five ActionLink in your view.

```
@Html.ActionLink("First Link","Index",new{id=1},new{@class="btn btn-primary"})
@Html.ActionLink("Second Link","Index",new{id=2},new{@class="btn btn-primary"})
@Html.ActionLink("Third Link","Index",new{id=3},new{@class="btn btn-primary"})
@Html.ActionLink("Fourth Link","Index",new{id=4},new{@class="btn btn-primary"})
@Html.ActionLink("Fifth Link","Index",new{id=5},new{@class="btn btn-primary"})
```

Then you need to create a actionMethod as below.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
   return view(id);
}
```

Then again in your View

```
@model int //binding data in view
......
......
@if(Model==1)
{
   //display view 1
}
elseif(Model==2)
{
   //display view 2
}
....
.....
else if(Model==5)
{
  //display view 5
}
```

I hope it works !